# How to get .post to open a url instead of generating html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento-1.9

So on my php page I have this which takes me to the shopping cart page.

```
header("Location: ".Mage::helper('checkout/cart')-
>getAddUrl($product).'?product='.$pId.'&qty=1' );
```

I am using .post to post the data to the php page but it returns HTML content of the page instead of opening the page. Note I only added alert to just look at what was being generated. So how do I get it to just take me to the page when I post?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function(Product)
    {
       $.post( "tocart.php", { sku:sku })
         .done(function(data) 
         {
          alert(data);
         });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The entire point of Ajax is that it *doesn't* take you to a new page.

If you don't want to stay on the same page, then don't use Ajax. For that matter, don't use JavaScript.

Just use a regular HTML form.

```
<form action="tocart.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="sku" value="sku">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep your application async, it's better to receive JSON data and decide what to do on the client. Otherwise, you can use traditional html forms with action set to your php script.